# Sum of dynamically generated fields in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query of dynamically calculated fields:

```
SELECT 5 * (`Mean (all)` +0.01735568 )/(0.07268901) AS rank1, 
5 * (`CVaR 95` +0.51612 )/(0.53212) AS rank2, 
5 * (`Hurst` - 0.2 )/(0.7717653) AS rank3, 
5 * (`MaxDD` +6.200000762939453 )/(16.200000762939) AS rank4, 
5 * (`Positive % 12` - 0.3 )/(1) AS rank5
FROM `quant1`
```

It works fine, but I need to add another dynamic field which is equal to rank1+rank2...+rank 5. So, I am adding another field like

```
SELECT 5 * (`Mean (all)` +0.01735568 )/(0.07268901) AS rank1, 
5 * (`CVaR 95` +0.51612 )/(0.53212) AS rank2, 
5 * (`Hurst` - 0.2 )/(0.7717653) AS rank3, 
5 * (`MaxDD` +6.200000762939453 )/(16.200000762939) AS rank4, 
5 * (`Positive % 12` - 0.3 )/(1) AS rank5,
rank1+rank2+rank3+rank4+rank5 AS rank
FROM `quant1`
```

It generates an error "unknown column rank1". Interesting that exactly the same query works fine with MS Access.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you cannot reference other aliases, but you can define variables in the select, so try this instead:

```
SELECT
   @rank1 := 5 * (`Mean (all)` +0.01735568 )/(0.07268901) AS rank1, 
   @rank2 := 5 * (`CVaR 95` +0.51612 )/(0.53212) AS rank2, 
   @rank3 := 5 * (`Hurst` - 0.2 )/(0.7717653) AS rank3, 
   @rank4 := 5 * (`MaxDD` +6.200000762939453 )/(16.200000762939) AS rank4, 
   @rank5 := 5 * (`Positive % 12` - 0.3 )/(1) AS rank5,
   @rank1 + @rank2 + @rank3 + @rank4 + @rank5 AS rank
FROM `quant1`
```

It is ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an alias in the same `SELECT` statement, put it inside a subquery instead, like this:

```
SELECT rank1, rank2, rank3, rank4, rank5,
  rank1 + rank2 + rank3 + rank4 + rank5 AS rank
FROM
(

    SELECT 5 * (`Mean (all)` +0.01735568 )/(0.07268901) AS rank1, 
    5 * (`CVaR 95` +0.51612 )/(0.53212) AS rank2, 
    5 * (`Hurst` - 0.2 )/(0.7717653) AS rank3, 
    5 * (`MaxDD` +6.200000762939453 )/(16.200000762939) AS rank4, 
    5 * (`Positive % 12` - 0.3 )/(1) AS rank5
    FROM `quant1`
) AS t
```

Comment: It works... The exec time for 10,000 rows is 0.062 sec slightly worse than the solution of Mats Kindahl below.

Comment: Note that sub-queries have historically not been good for the optimizer. It has improved in the latest MySQL version, but it does push the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ways.
1. Use these query as subquery:

```
select R.*,R.rank1+R.rank2+R.rank3+R.rank4+R.rank5 AS rank from (
SELECT 5 * (`Mean (all)` +0.01735568 )/(0.07268901) AS rank1, 
5 * (`CVaR 95` +0.51612 )/(0.53212) AS rank2, 
5 * (`Hurst` - 0.2 )/(0.7717653) AS rank3, 
5 * (`MaxDD` +6.200000762939453 )/(16.200000762939) AS rank4, 
5 * (`Positive % 12` - 0.3 )/(1) AS rank5
FROM `quant1`
) as R
```

or
2. 
in your query replace:
rank1+rank2+rank3+rank4+rank5
with (5 * (`Mean (all)` +0.01735568 )/(0.07268901)) + (5 * (`CVaR 95` +0.51612 )/(0.53212)) ..etc..

Comment: Personally, I don't recommend option 2 - they're going to get out of sync really fast.  Using a subquery is probably the only way to go.

Comment: Option 1 generates an error:"Error Code: 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias". You need to add "AS someTable" at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try a sub-query, like:

```
SELECT *, rank1+rank2+rank3+rank4+rank5 AS rank 
FROM (   
  SELECT 5 * (`Mean (all)` +0.01735568 )/(0.07268901) AS rank1, 
  5 * (`CVaR 95` +0.51612 )/(0.53212) AS rank2, 
  5 * (`Hurst` - 0.2 )/(0.7717653) AS rank3, 
  5 * (`MaxDD` +6.200000762939453 )/(16.200000762939) AS rank4, 
  5 * (`Positive % 12` - 0.3 )/(1) AS rank5,
  FROM `quant1`
)  QuantRank
```